# how to get document with list of objects? - firestore

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get documents with list of objects in firestore

```
doc 1
     id:123
     name: product1
     categories:
    [0]
    catid:21
    name: category21
    [1]
    catid:34
    name: category34
doc 2 
     id:456
     name: product2
     categories:
    [0]
    catid:9
    name: category9
    [1]
    catid:4
    name: category4
```

i finally reach how to add a product with a list of categoies objects (as i defined the categories in the productModel below), but i can't get the products with list of categories objects :(
i tried in the ProductModel

```
if(data[CATEGORIES] != null){
  //  categories.add(data[CATEGORIES].map());
   categories.add(CategoryModel.fromMap(data[CATEGORIES]));
   // categories.addAll(data[CATEGORIES].values());
  //  categories = data[CATEGORIES].map((i) => i.fromMap());
   };
```

but all of them don't work with msg:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, 
dynamic>'
```

firestore:

```
getProducts(ProductProvider productProvider) async{
  QuerySnapshot snapshot= await Firestore.instance.collection('products').getDocuments();
  List<ProductModel> _productList=[];
   snapshot.documents.forEach((document){
    ProductModel product= ProductModel.fromMap(document.data);
    _productList.add(product);
  });
  productProvider.productList=_productList;
}

uploadProduct(ProductModel product) async {
  CollectionReference productRef = Firestore.instance.collection('products');
    DocumentReference documentRef = await productRef.add(product.toMap());
    product.id = documentRef.documentID;
    print('uploaded product successfully: ${product.toString()}');
    await documentRef.setData(product.toMap(), merge: true);
  }
}
```

data model

```
ProductModel{
String id;
String name;
List<CategoryModel> categories

ProductModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data){
   id = data['id'];
   name= data['name'];
   categories = data['categories']; // ?? 
}
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name':name,
      'categories': categories.map((i) => i.toMap()).toList(),  // this worked well 

};}}

CategoryModel{
String id;
String name;

CategoryModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data){
   id = data['id'];
   name= data['name'];
}
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name':name,
};}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data['categories']` is `Map<String, dynamic>[]`,

you can map the data to category model list.

```
    categories = data['categories']
        .map<CategoryModel>((value) => CategoryModel.fromMap(value))
        .toList();
```